# Hide/Unhide Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm looking for help with a macro that will show a set of columns then another that will show that same set of columns that is assigned to two separate buttons.

Currently I have the `Hide Bootcamp` and `Show Bootcamp` buttons that will accomplish this task, but I know that columns will need to be added in to this work sheet that will throw off the ranges in the future (<> Column I OR Columns BJ:CO). Does anybody have a solution that will keep the range integrity as columns are added/removed to the worksheet?

**Worksheet Link**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17H9QMJ7Lmznon8G0dO4MGkidE0b6ymrvgt7fTE9gQBw/edit?usp=sharing

**Current Code Below**

**Hide Columns**

```
function HideBootcamp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

   spreadsheet.getRange('I:I').activate();
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());

   spreadsheet.getRange('BJ:CO').activate();
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());

   spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
};
```

**Show Columns**

```
function ShowBootcamp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

   spreadsheet.getRange('I:I').activate();
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());

   spreadsheet.getRange('BJ:CO').activate();
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns());

   spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
};
```

Comment: Do your columns all have names at the top? If so, will the names remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

## Hide Column By Name

If you answer yes to both of my questions in the comment above then this will hide your column for you.  All you have to do is give the function the name of your column in the top row and of course you will have to change the sheet name probably.

```
function hideColumnByName(name) {
  var name=name||'HDR10';//debug
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn())
  var hA=rg.getValues()[0];
  sh.hideColumns(hA.indexOf(name)+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is missing activate range.

```
function hideColumnByName(name) {
  var name=name||'HDR10';//debug
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).activate();
  var hA=rg.getValues()[0];
  sh.hideColumns(hA.indexOf(name)+1);
}
```